# MS Access 2010: How Can I Avoid Uneditable Query Results?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am working on my first Access 2010 database and have run into a problem editing the recordset returned from a query.  [This excellent blog entry](http://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.com/2009/11/this-recordset-is-not-updateable-why.html) details several scenarios which can result in uneditable query results.  I believe my query results are not editable because my query has a Cartesian Join.

I'm not sure how to avoid this, however.  The three tables involved are:

- episodes

  - Individual television episodes
  - Primary key: "episode_id"
- aridates

  - Individual airdates for a given episode
  - Primary key: "airdate_id"
  - Related to "episodes" by "airdate_episode_id"
- startdates

  - Individual download start-dates for a given episode

    - i.e. when a given episode will be available to download
  - Primary key: "startdate_id"
  - Related to "episodes" by "startdate_episode_id"

So, there is no (and *I think* can be no) direct relationship between airdates and startdates.  However, this makes the query:

```
SELECT episodes.episode_id, episodes.episode_number, episodes.episode_title, airdates.airdate_region_id, airdates.airdate_date
FROM (episodes LEFT JOIN airdates ON episodes.episode_id = airdates.airdate_episode_id) LEFT JOIN startdates ON episodes.episode_id = startdates.startdate_episode_id;
```

return a recordset which is not editable.  I need to be able to see the episode name and number along with the airdate in order to enter a startdate (episodes can not be made available for download before they have aired).  So essentially, in this view I only need to be able to edit "startdates.stardate_date".

Thanks in advance for any suggestions... a screenshot of the relationship in question [can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4BKa.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create this query:

```
SELECT
    episodes.episode_id,
    episodes.episode_number,
    episodes.episode_title,
    airdates.airdate_region_id,
    airdates.airdate_date
FROM
    episodes LEFT JOIN airdates
    ON episodes.episode_id = airdates.airdate_episode_id;
```

Use it as the recordsource for a new form.  Then create another form which uses a query of only the startdates table as its record source.

Add the second form as a subform to the first form.  On the property sheet for the subform **control**, make the link master field episode_id and the link child field startdate_episode_id.

If you are successful, the subform will display startdates rows where the startdate_episode_id matches the episode_id of the main form's current record.  And if you add a new row in the subform, its startdate_episode_id will "inherit" the episode_id from the main form.

I emphasized **control** earlier because that point can be confusing.  The subform control is a member of the main form's controls collection, and the subform control contains the subform.  You must find the link master/child field properties on the subform control, not the actual subform itself.

Comment: Thanks Hans!  This did the trick... I need to play around with the formatting of the forms to make it as usable as possible, but this is definitely what I needed.